# Brake Pads on a Jeep Patriot

Tags: brakes, jeep, brake-pad

I have recently changed the brake pads on my Jeep Patriot. It seems to me that the pads just "sit" inside the caliper as opposed to actually being attached (in some shape, way, or form) to something.

To compare, when I've changed the brake pads on my Ford Escape, the brake pads had something like a spring on the back that would keep it attached to the piston (this process makes sense to me)... the point here is that there is mechanism on the pad to secure it in place. The Jeep's brakes didn't have anything of the sort... Am I missing something, or how do the brakes not just continually rub against the rotor? Thanks in advance!